# get_user_by("email... not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Here I attempt to get a user by email, passing it an email stored in the `student` variable.

```
$user = get_user_by("email", $student);
```

Student variable

```
echo $student;
>>> xxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxx.co.uk
```

I can confirm this email is correct and exists as a users email.

```
var_dump($user);
>>> (false)
```

I'm currently editing within a pdf_certificates generator plugin.

Is there any reason I shouldn't be able to access this user? Cheers guys.

Comment: this user is exist? or may be wrong with email try trim() `$user = get_user_by('email', trim($student));`

Comment: Maybe there are blankspaces or the field is case-sensitive and differs? Make sure `email` exists (not only username or something) and you are looking into the correct table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    $email = "xxx@xxx.com";
    if ( email_exists( $email ) ){  
        $user = get_user_by("email", $email);
        print_r($user);
        echo $username = $user->user_login;
    }else{
       echo "Email id does not exist.";
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

get_user_by("user_email", $email)

Comment: How is this helpful in any way?